# How to optimize the synchronized method in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

I saw this legacy code in my application which caused threads blocked on the `synchronized` method in production.

```
private synchronized void productMapBuilder(List<Product> products) {
        Map<String, Set<Product>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Product product : products) {
            map.putAll(buildProductMap(product));// this call another method which isn't synchronised.
        }
        this.productsMap = map;
    }
```

Now, as `List<product> products` are passed to this `productMapBuilder` I know it's a thread specific and only shared variable here between threads are `productsMap`.

**then do we really need to put `synchronized` on entire method ?**

Also I can't think of any other way to optimize this method, As I am not an expert in concurrent programs, hence any valuable resources and suggestions are most welcome :)

Comment: `Map<String, Set<Product>> productsMap = new HashMap<>();` is not shared between thread. It is always created when this method is called.

Comment: You can try using ConcurrentHashMap if productsMap is shared across threads, but from the snippet it doesn't look like it is shared. Also, if buildProductMap is thread safe, that can be refactored out of synchronized scope.

Comment: @VikramSingh, sorry for the confusion but if you notice its assigned to same name variable `this.productsMap= = productsMap` and when I mentioned shared I meant of `this.productsMap`

Comment: renamed the variable names to avoid confusion.

Comment: Is it not that only `this.productsMap = map;` needs to be synchronized?

Comment: Whether this can be changed or not depends on more code than just this. Are there other methods which synchronize on the same lock? How is `this.productsMap` used? Etc.

Comment: @Kayaman, they have declared `this.productMap` as volatile and then its used frequently in other non-synchronized methods of the same class. Also other method which call this `synchronized` product maps builder are not `synchronized`.

Comment: @Kayaman *How is this.productsMap used?* - agree

Comment: @user7851946 "other method which call this...", but if they call that method, it doesn't mean those methods would need to be synchronized. It almost sounds like the variable just needs to be `volatile` and the `synchronized` was added because someone thought it's needed.

Comment: @Kayaman, so r u suggesting, if we just declare a shared variable as volatile then we don't need to use the `synchronized ` while updating it ?

Comment: @user7851946 no, that's not what I meant. What I mean is that there's only a single shared resource in that method, in `this.productsMap = map;` where `volatile` guarantees visibility. Although if `buildProductMap()` is a heavy operation, the synchronization may have been abused to prevent multiple threads from performing that at the same time. I don't know what the real case is, and I'm not going to start guessing too much.

Comment: @Kayaman, yeah `buildProductMap` is a costly operation as it calls in other method which also does some complex calculation. so in this can we just use the  `synchronize` block only on the code `this.productsMap = map` ? let me know if you have more questions I would try to give as much as information so you dont have to guess :)

Comment: @user7851946 you wouldn't need a synchronized block at all, since the variable is volatile. But removing the synchronization allows all threads to perform the costly operation at the same time, raising the CPU% but if that's acceptable, then you can just remove all the synchronization from the method and see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202251/discussion-between-user7851946-and-kayaman).

Answer (score -1):

Since `productsMap` is a instance level variable, that's why this method has been synchronized. Assuming `buildProductMap` is just a utility class and doesn't requires synchronization, one reason you are seeing threads blocked ( and not dead-locked) on `productMapBuilder` is perhaps `products` is a huge list and it is taking time to process.When multiple threads are hitting this piece of code, there is high contention for object level lock. Low contention synchronization is cheap but it starts to create problem in high contention. By the way have you analyzed the thread dumps to see if indeed this method is the real cause ? Also `productsMap` is method level variable so no need for synchronization for that, it's just because of `this.productsMap = productsMap`. However I have one question - the reason you are assigning productsMap to instance level variable ( and hence need for synchronization) is that you will be reusing it ( and not recalculating) it. Is this a one time initialization or this happens for each user request ?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, contains unrelated things about "class level variables" (it's an instance variable) and lock contention.

Comment: "class level variables" is typo which I have corrected - I do have mentioned "instance level" below.